# Show that a $5 \times 4$ Matrix of row rank $3$ has nontrivial solutions for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

> **Statement**: Let $A$ be a $5 \times 4$-Matrix with row rank 3. Show that $Ax=0$ has nontrivial solutions.

This is a homework problem, as a hint I am given one formula (which we didn't discuss in class yet) but intuition wise I don't understand how it should help me at all to verify this statement. My tutor went about this as follows, consider: $$ F: \begin{cases} V & \longrightarrow W \\ v & \longmapsto A \circ v \end{cases} $$
know that: Row Rank of A = Column Rank of A = $\dim(\text{Im}(A))=\dim(\text{Im}(F))$ and make use of

> $\dim(V)=\dim(\text{Kernel}(F))+\dim(\text{Im}(F)) \tag{given}$

I do understand the given Formula, but I don't understand how to apply it, since the Row rank of $A$ is equal to $3$, so is the Column Rank and therefore the dimension of the Image of $F$ is also equal to $3$. Can I make a statement about the dimension of $V$? I know that $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ but that doesn't help me much with the dimension of $V$.

Some hints or insights, especial intuition wise insights, would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *nontrivial* solutions?

Comment: Oh you're right, excuse me please! My english is very troublesome today, I will update it immediately +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nullity-rank theorem is stated for the general case and you can apply it to your situation:

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^4$, $W=\mathbb{R}^5$ and define $F(v)=Av$, for $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$. Then the image of $F$ is the column space, which has dimension $3$ because $A$ has rank $3$. Therefore $N(A)$, which is the solution set of $Ax=0$ and the kernel of $F$, has dimension $4-3=1$ and so contains nonzero vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much, all it took was your phrasing for me to understand this problem with a special highlight on "and the kernel of $F$, has dimension $1$ and so contains nonzero vectors" thanks.